# Programmatically recieve data from bluetooth headset in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, streaming

I'm developing an android application in which I need to receive some raw data stream from the BlueTooth device that is embedded in HeadSet. How I'll receive it? Do I need a specific library? or do I just use BlueTooth conectivity.

Comment: What data exactly you want to get?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just want to receive the Jason Array Data over Bluetooth socket